# Cannot use Server.MapPath to access a external file

Tags: c#, asp.net, path, filepath

I have a xml file which is in a folder in the solution. I tried to access it using `Server.MapPath`. It was working fine in a aspx page of a different project. When I tried to access the file in my class library project, I am not supposed to use `Server.MapPath`. So I tried with `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath`. Problem is this class library project is calling from a separate WCF service project, so current server is WCF service project's server. So it ended up with error path is not valid.

This is what I tried- `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("./folder/conf.xml.config")`

Any solution?

`System.Web` is already imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a **[virtual-directory](/questions/tagged/virtual-directory)** inside the **[web-services](/questions/tagged/web-services)**. This **[virtual-directory](/questions/tagged/virtual-directory)** will point to Physical location of **"folder/conf.xml.config"**.

Once this is done, you can access it using your existing code like below...

```
Server.MapPath("folder/conf.xml.config")
```

Answer (score 0):

`Server.MapPath` works only with files that are inside the website and is used by specifying a relative location:

```
string configFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/config.xml.config");
```

If you want to access a file from some other location you will have to manually provide the absolute path to it:

```
string configFile = @"c:\work\some_folder\config.xml.config";
```

Comment: Darin- I am not supposed to use absolute path method you mentioned above, the path can be changed when some one takes this solution into other machine.

Comment: Then this could be a parameter stored in your web.config. Anyway, there's no other way to access files which could be anywhere on the filesystem other than specifying their absolute location. Otherwise how ASP.NET will be able to find the file? Remember that once you deploy your web application on a web server there's no longer any notion of Visual Studio solutions or projects or relative paths to the solution file. What you end up with is a website deployed on some folder on the server where you could use the MapPath method to access files inside this folder.

Comment: And add on- its a class library not MVC4 project. I am trying to access file from a folder which is inside class library.

Comment: As I already explained there's no such notion as *folder inside class library*. The class library is referenced in your ASP.NET MVC application and when you deploy this application the original location where this class library came from doesn't have any meaning. So you could copy the file as well and make it part of the web application and then access it with `Server.MapPath`. If you cannot do that or don't want to do it you will have to specify the absolute location.